# How can I validate fields in a webpage?

Tags: telerik, telerik-test-studio

How can I validate fields?  Is the following correct?

- Navigate to : 'http://BusinessAccounting.aspx'
- Press Tab
- radmaskedtextbox: type 'admin' text action.
- Type 'admin' into PasswordPasswordbox
- Verify Item0Textboxview's visibility is Visible
- Click RadBtnSignInRadbutton

Answer (score 1):

In telerik test studio, the easiest way to add verifications is to use the recorder. Hover over the field you want to verify, then use the dialogs to build a verification rule for the state of the field:

1. Hover over the field:

   [image: Telerik Test Studio, blue icon for recording actions]
2. Select 'Build Verification' from the dialog:

   [image: Telerik Test Studio, elements menu for recording actions]
3. Choose whatever kind of verification you want:
   [image: Telerik Test Studio, Verification Sentence Builder]